# RSA signatures that allow hash to move around in block

Tags: rsa, padding, attack

I'm looking at a broken RSA signature padding implementation in a real device.  It's a very-badly implemented version of PKCS #1-like encoding, but before PKCS added the DER-encoded hash identifier.

The signature format is *intended* to be:

`00 01 FF FF FF FF FF ... FF FF 00 <SHA-1 hash>`

However, for some reason, the programmers saw how the second byte can also be `02` in PKCS and in that case any nonzero padding could replace the `FF` bytes.  This is misinterpreting PKCS, because that's for *encryption* padding, not the *signature* padding.  Allowing encryption-mode PKCS padding is a major mistake.

A second mistake is that the implementation does not require the SHA-1 hash to be flushed right.  (In `01` mode, it does require that there be at least 8 `FF` bytes, making attacks on `01` impractical.)  Thus, the *actual* padding format, if abused to be `02` format, is this:

`00 02 <nonzero garbage> 00 <SHA-1 hash> <garbage>`

If the public exponent were $3$, both the `01` and `02` forms would be trivially broken by taking the floor of the cube root (Bleichenbacher).  Alas, the public exponent is $65537$.

Without an oracle, is there an attack against this?

Note that if there were an algorithm that could generate numbers whose 65537th power contained the desired SHA-1 hash anywhere within the message, leaving the rest of the number corrupted randomly, such an algorithm would succeed in $2^{26}$ or so outputs.